# かきます（to write) when used with the particle に

Tags: grammar, verbs, particle-に

From what my test book says in the vocab section the verb かきます usually takes the particles を for things and に for people. I'm pretty sure that you would use を like this.

> ともだちに てがみを かきました - I wrote a letter to a friend/friends

So then I guess my question would be then for に would I just make the sentence like this?

> ともだちに かきました - I wrote to a friend/friends(?)

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: If I heard you just say "友達に書きました", I would want to ask "何を？" You would say 友達に書きました when responding to a question like 誰に手紙を書いたんですか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a precision, I don't think the distinction is really between things and people and it's not related to the verb 書く either, it's just about the meaning of を and に.

The particle を marks the direct object in this case. Therefore it follows **what** you write.

The particle に marks the point of arrival/goal of an action/recipient of something in this case. Therefore it follows the **recipient** of the letter.

> 政府に手紙を書いた。
>   I wrote a letter to the governement.

For the rest, see the comments below your question.